# Git and Github. How to reuse files for a repository

Tags: git, macos, github

I created a git folder on window and used it for my first commit to GitHub. I have now started using Mac. How do I go about editing my repository since I have the folder/readme file saved on windows. How do I recreate this on Mac.

Comment: Just clone it from your github. This is the fundation od using version control systems.

Comment: did you push all your changes from windows to GitHub? if so, just `clone` the repository to you Mac.

Comment: one caveat, in sharing (or even migrating) a repo between a windows machine and a mac:  The windows machine will almost certainly have a case-insensitive filesystem, while the mac will almost certainly have a case-sensitive file system.  Usually doesn't matter, but it is a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [clone your repository](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/#platform-mac) on your mac, with the link provided in github.

Basically, you just need to do

```
git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

(though your connections need to be configured, or you will be prompted username and password)

Alternatively you can also use the [GitHub app for Mac](http://mac.github.com/).

---

When you want to make some changes, you can commit them and push them on the github repo, and then pull the changes on your windows repo (or inverse).

Comment: It says invalid username or password, then I created a new password token and when I tried it again it kept on saying Repository not found.

Comment: you can try using the github app : http://mac.github.com/ . But at some point, you need to have the correct repository name and the correct credentials.